# Can Android endpoints service object be Static across threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using generated `Google Cloud Endpoints for Android` in `Android studio`.

All examples that I saw use an `AsyncTask` and declare the service object (here called "api") in the following manner:

```
Api.Builder builder = new Api.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null);
api = builder.build();
```

I am new to Android and Endpoints I was wondering if the service object needs to be declared in each `AsyncTask` or if it can be made static and accessed from anywhere, even from different asynchronous tasks.

Can I see this somewhere by looking at the object? Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know

- It would be very surprising if the endpoint proxy (your `Api` object) was not thread safe. It should be documented if it is not the case
- I would reuse the object, but this does not mean it has to be static. You can certainy pass it as a parameter of your async tasks.